# How to Set Values in Shared Preferences using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

here is the Method:

```
public class SessionManager {
     public static void setStatus(Context context, int value, String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putInt(key,value);
            editor.commit();
     }

     public static int getStatus(Context c,String key){
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            int a = pref.getInt(key,0);
            return a;   
    }
}
```

i am trying to set value "1"  in shared Preferences on `PostExecuteMethod()` of Async Task:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();       
    Log.i("Setting Status Variables Value in Customer:",""+AndroidUtil.getStatusForServices());
    SessionManager.setStatus(context,1,"status");
    Log.i("Setting Status Variables Value in Customer after:",""+AndroidUtil.getStatusForServices());  
}
```

But it still it saves 0 in  Variable Here is the Logcat:

```
01-04 03:31:32.430: I/Setting Status Variables Value in Customer:(20879): 0
01-04 03:31:32.440: I/Setting Status Variables Value in Customer after:(20879): 0
```

Comment: yes i m sure about async task completed

Comment: what you have in AndroidUtil.getStatusForServices(). Post that too

Comment: Looks good, maybe change to use getApplicationContext(), like: getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()), and getDefaultSharedPreferences(c.getApplicationContext());

Comment: Sorry i got mistake actually every time i run app the value in AndroidUtil.getStatus () returns me "0" because it initialized default value

Comment: @marcin_j  this is not the case

Comment: post getStatusForServices function as well you might be using wrong key

Comment: @vipulmittal  key was fine but unfortunately i was not calling  getStatus(Context c,String key)   this was the problem no one found this problem

Comment: this single LOC spoiled my 2 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this in the following way.

First you will need declare the SharedPreferences  inside the Activity in this manner:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
   {

    SharedPreferences sp;
    int val=2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp=this.getSharedPreferences("service_validation", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        val=sp.getInt("VALIDATION", val);
                .
                .// you can put here anything code
                .
        }
.
.// you can put here anything method
.
.
}
```

Now when you would like to save the value in background asynch task. Please put this code inside onPostExecute(..) method in this manner:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
editor.putInt("VALIDATION", 1);
editor.commit();
```

It is better to use this code on doInBackground(..) method.

After saving the value, refresh or re-run the Activity. It will show the effect .

Enjoy the code!!

If my answer will help you then please support my answer.

Comment: can u please explain why its better to define code in  doinbackground ()

Comment: In background we always like to do heavy work or actual tasks. Though background method does not show any output, it's only used for insertion or get the value. So, it will be best way to put or insert value in background which can handle you activity safely . :)

Comment: actually i want to put values on completion of background task as soon as my background task ends i want to save values as "1"

Comment: Ok, there is no problem. you can easily do this. First write your background task code inside doInBackground() method and after that in the last you can use this or you can also write sharedpreference code inside onPostExecute() method.